# trying to get many-to-many related data in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, many-to-many

I am building a website in Django where messages have tags. Below you can see my models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    message_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_tags(self, tag_id):
        return self.message.filter(tags__tag_id=tag_id)

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here's my views.py as well.

```
popular_tags = Tag.objects.filter(messages__date_created__gt=now).annotate(num=Count('messages')).order_by('-num')[:25]
```

What I am trying to do here is that I want to show tags with the most number of messages. After I do that, I want the tags to show which messages have that tag. So I know I can't do query filtering in template, and that's why I added get_tags under the Message model. So with that I've tried writing the right template, but I am not sure what went wrong with it.

```
{% for q in popular_tags %}
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><h5>{{ q.tag_name }}</h5> </td>
        {% for m in message.get_tags %}
        <td align="left"><h5>{{ m.title }} </h5></td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I am not getting any errors, it's just that no messages are being shown while the tags are correctly displayed. Any ideas how and where I should fix?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything special, Django's ORM takes care of it, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference

The following should work:

```
{% for q in popular_tags %}
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><h5>{{ q.tag_name }}</h5> </td>
        {% for m in q.message_set.all %}
        <td align="left"><h5>{{ m.title }} </h5></td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks bruno. Unfortunately it's not working either. I am not getting any errors, but the titles still aren't being displayed.

Comment: when I was testing stuff in shell, I got this error AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'message_set'. Do you think this could be the reason?

Comment: @user2857014 I don't have your project installed and I don't know what "stuff" you tested in your shell so I cannot seriously answer your question. You may want to checkout whether the descriptor is `tag.message_set` (as per the doc) or `tag.messages` (as far as I'm concerned I always set the `related_name` on `ForeignKey` and `ManyToMany` fields (I don't like the default) so I don't know for sure which one is right using the defaults. wrt/ the error you got in the shell, you were obviously on a `QuerySet` instead of a `Tag` instance... You want a `Tag` instance having associated messages.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a function within `Tag` rather than `Message`:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_msgs(self):
        return Message.objects.filter(tags__tag_id=tag_id)
```

Hence, the template should be:

```
{% for q in popular_tags %}
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><h5>{{ q.tag_name }}</h5> </td>
        {% for m in q.get_msgs %}
        <td align="left"><h5>{{ m.title }} </h5></td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Right. You can remove `get_tags`.

Comment: @arocks: your code is broken (NameError on tag_id). And you don't need a special method anyway, Django's ORM takes care of adding the proper descriptor to your models.